# Kong Ingress Controller has no effect on Kong Plugins

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I have gone through kong-ingress-controller [deployment](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/deployment/gke.md) and [getting started](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/guides/getting-started.md) doc and done everything mentioned.

1. Update User Permissions
2. Deploy Kong Ingress Controller
3. Setup environment variables
4. Created Ingress with Routes

Everything works fine, I can access my applications based on the routes. But when I added rate-limit plugins or any other plugins it does not take any effect.

ingress.yaml :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: my-ingress
 namespace: default
 annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
  plugins.konghq.com: http-ratelimit, http-auth
spec:
 rules:
  - host: foo.bar
  http:
    paths:
    - path: /users
      backend:
        serviceName: my-service
        servicePort: 80
```

rate-limit.yaml :

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
 name: http-ratelimit
 labels:
   global: 'true'
config:
 minute: 5
plugin: rate-limiting
```

But the rate limit plugin has no effect on my ingress.

**NB: The kong-ingress-controller is in kong namespace but the other resources are in default namespace. I tried to move everything to kong namespace then the plugins works but service does not work as it is in default namespace.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Kong docs](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/guides/using-kongplugin-resource.md), the rate-limit YAML looks correct. If the resource is configured correctly, Kong is not matching the request against the ingress resource because the user is not sending the correct request.

Comment: No it's a simple GET request. I removed all the plugins,consumers,ingress and created again and it started working. Now if I want remove key-auth plugin and add oath2 plugin, the new plugin is not taking any effect.

Comment: Remove annotation from the Ingress/Service yamls. 
Create a new kong plugin for oauth2 and add/update annotation in Ingress/Service with a newly created plugin.

Answer (score 0):

KongPlugin, KongIngress should be in same namespace as Service. YAML provides looks correct. 
There must be something wrong in ingress yamls annotation and configuration.Is your service annotated with Ingress object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this annotation to your KongPlugin:

```
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
```

So try with

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
 name: http-ratelimit
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
[...]
```

Comment: And what exactly does this annotation do? Please explain the code, so other people can benefit more from your answer then just code without explaination

Comment: At least, it makes it work. :) While researching for solving the same problem as the original poster had, I stumbled upon [this bug report](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/885#issuecomment-702453875), tried it, and it worked.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with the OAuth2 plugin. It doesn't have any effect when applied to the ingress resource. I tried the above solution too (adding an annotation) but I do not get an http 401 error when the curl api request is made without passing the authorization header. Refer to this yaml (https://pastebin.com/yLhEbJTt) and this one (https://pastebin.com/qVgf8YG2) for my config. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I wanted to apply the `KongPlugin` on a specific Ingress Resource/Route.

What worked for me was to create the `KongPlugin` object in the **same namespace** where the Ingress Resource (and therefore, the target service) lived.